# Settings in Oracle client and Server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Are the settings of oracle server like , the nls_date_format,.... attributes (I don't know really how many of these kind settings are there) , will be downloaded to the oracle client running on different machine by connecting to the SQL*plus using server host name?

Or the client will maitain its different set , assuming the client is SQL*Plus.

If the client is having its own settings ,is there any way If I can set the same settings as server. like export all settings from server and import those settings to client.

If the client is SQL Developer , is there any way to maintain the sync. between server settings and client's.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the settings (about 20 variables) from the NLS-Views (`NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`, `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS`, `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`). By `show parameter nls` you can view the actual settings in SQL*Plus.

These can be altered by sysdba in several ways:

- The database parameters are read from (s)pfile while startup. They can be altered via `ALTER SYSTEM SCOPE=SPFILE` if you use spfile. If you use pfile you have to edit it manually
- The instance parameters are set by `ALTER SYSTEM SCOPE=MEMORY` and will be lost upon shutdown
- Both at once can be altered using `SCOPE=BOTH`. This will be applied immediately and survive the shutdown

The client can override this for his own session in (at least?) two ways:

- Set it for your session by `ALTER SESSION` in SQL*Plus
- Set environment variables before client startup via `export NLS_...=...` in the shell

The latter overrides the earlier ones, so `SESSION` beats `INSTANCE` which eats `DATABASE`.

For your question: you can use a `SELECT * FROM NLS_INSTANCE_SETTINGS` and apply these to your current session by `ALTER SESSION SET ...` for each of these variables (maybe via some PL/SQL procedure). Another way would be just to unset all session parameters so that the instance parameters will be used.

If you do not set any NLS variables (especially `NLS_LANG`) in your environment, your session should be the same as the instance or the database ones. In practice this will never work as expected as you always have some `locale` settings that produce weired results in SQLP*Plus. ;-)